# Why using RISC-V over off-the-shelf chips is more energy efficient?

Tags: risc-v

I am not an expert on the world of chips, but as a developer, I understand quite well how they work and what problem each chip solves.

I have been increasingly curious about RISC-V and, among other claims, one that captures my attention is that allowing manufacturers to design chips with only the instruction set they need will be more energy efficient over using off-the-shelf chips that can include many other instructions that are not necessary.

Here is an oversimplified example. Let's imagine I want to build a dumb calculator that can only do additions. My choice is now:

- buy an existing chip that handles additions, among many other arithmetic operations which I won't use
- OR I could use RISC-V to design (and manufacture) a chip that only has the instructions needed to make additions.

Why would the RISC-V chip be more energy efficient? What cost does it bear to have more instructions that you use/need in your chip?

Comment: Possibly related: x86's purported power hungriness due to complex instruction decoders: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/cooldc16/cooldc16-paper-hirki.pdf TLDR: Authors estimate that a few % of power consumption could be saved by trimmed instruction decoding.

Comment: In your example below, if your existing chip is an ASIC made for the task and to be as low power as possible would be near impossible to beat with any CPU. Only exception I can think of is if the ASIC is made in some very old power hungry process and the CPU is made in a state of the art process for low power. CPUs tends to be sold for speed foremost and energy efficiency secondly, so it's unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been increasingly curious about RISC-V and, among other claims, one that captures my attention is that allowing manufacturers to design chips with only the instruction set they need will be more energy efficient over using off-the-shelf chips that can include many other instructions that are not necessary.

That seems like an overly proud claim. That's not the case; sure, if you design your instruction set to make it easy for compilers/assemblers (even the human kind) to solve the problem they're having in few efficient instructions, that will make the software running use less energy.

Likewise, if you implement a processor that has a lot of instructions that you don't use, its decoder stage will end up unwieldily big, which might need energy in itself – but honestly, probably not that much. The question is whether you having unused instructions also means you have functional units idling away, using power for no reason – but that's not going to be the case in most modern processor designs: Processors with a complex instruction set including rarely-used instructions tend to decode instructions to microinstructions, anyway, so that these rare instructions just get implemented through microcode routines. And while these might be slow and power-inefficient, they don't get executed, so nothing lost.

Also, modern processors are able to completely power off unused functional units. So, the "idling" power loss is a bit of a case of "show me the actual numbers, or I assume that it's not as significant".

> Why would the RISC-V chip be more energy efficient?

It's not going to be more efficient, in general, than a similarly-optimized existing design. Chances might be that RISC-V is a relatively modern collection of instruction sets, designed with decades more of knowledge in actual use cases than, say, x86 or MIPS was.

But I don't see an inherent advantage that any RISC-V processor implementation would have for a given use case versus existing application-optimized designs; using, say, RISCV-BOOM instead of, say, the very legacy MSP430 in an application that really only calls for a 16 bit design with little math and no large memory will be *worse*. Same for using an intel XEON in a place where a VexRisc-V would have sufficed for a motor control job. Same, but the other way around, when it comes to 3D, number crunching or database applications: it would probably be pretty hard to beat an Apple M2 ARM (aarch64) CPU even with the most optimized-for-that RISC-V cores in terms of Watt per compute there.

> What cost does it bear to have more instructions that you use/need in your chip?

Having more instructions mostly costs in chip complexity / area, not in power usage per se, as described above.

Of course, if the complexity means that you can't design your silicon as optimized (simply for lack of compute time/memory and algorithms to optimize such a large design), then you'll be better off with a less complex design. But: RISC-V is certainly not the first RISC ISA ever. So, I feel like this is regurgitating claims from the 1980s/1990s that have long proven to be not as black and white.